# redux & webpack & flow: cannot transpile typed functions

Tags: webpack, redux, babeljs, flowtype

This is a line that I have in my Redux app:

```
export default connect<Props, OwnProps, _, _, _, _>(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)
```

however webpack throws an error while building the bundle:

```
ERROR in ./static/react/content_block_editor/EditorMain.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ; (287:28)
```

what should I install to fix this?

my `package.json` dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
  "axios": "^0.16.2",
  "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
  "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
  "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
  "brace": "^0.10.0",
  "clean-webpack-plugin": "^0.1.16",
  "connection-line": "^1.1.6",
  "css-loader": "^0.28.7",
  "eventing-bus": "^1.3.3",
  "filepond": "^3.3.0",
  "filepond-plugin-image-crop": "^2.0.0",
  "filepond-plugin-image-preview": "^3.1.3",
  "filepond-plugin-image-transform": "^3.0.3",
  "history": "^4.7.2",
  "informed": "^1.10.7",
  "lodash": "^4.17.11",
  "mime-types": "^2.1.21",
  "moment": "^2.22.2",
  "node-sass": "^4.9.4",
  "npm": "^6.4.1",
  "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
  "query-string": "^6.1.0",
  "rc-menu": "^7.4.19",
  "react": "^16.7.0",
  "react-ace": "^5.2.0",
  "react-bootstrap": "^0.31.5",
  "react-cookie": "^2.1.1",
  "react-dnd": "^5.0.0",
  "react-dnd-html5-backend": "^5.0.1",
  "react-dom": "^16.7.0",
  "react-draggable": "^3.0.5",
  "react-dropdown": "^1.6.2",
  "react-filepond": "^5.0.0",
  "react-input-mask": "^1.0.7",
  "react-paginate": "^5.2.4",
  "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
  "react-responsive-modal": "^3.4.0",
  "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
  "react-select": "^1.3.0",
  "react-switchery": "^1.2.3",
  "react-tagsinput": "^3.19.0",
  "redux": "^4.0.1",
  "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
  "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
  "styled-components": "^4.1.3",
  "uuid": "^3.3.2",
  "webpack-bundle-tracker": "^0.3.0",
  "@storybook/addon-actions": "^4.1.3",
  "@storybook/addon-console": "^1.1.0",
  "@storybook/addon-knobs": "^4.1.3",
  "@storybook/react": "^4.1.3",
  "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.0",
  "babel-preset-flow": "^6.23.0",
  "empty": "^0.10.1",
  "flow-bin": "^0.89.0",
  "flow-typed": "^2.5.1",
  "flow-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.0",
  "jest": "^23.6.0",
  "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.7",
  "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
  "webpack": "^4.28.0",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2"
}
```

my `.babelrc`:

```
{
    "presets": ["react", "es2015", "stage-0", "flow"],
    "plugins": ["babel-plugin-styled-components"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you'll need to upgrade to babel 7 in order to get support for the callsite type annotation syntax and implicit instantiation

[source](https://github.com/babel/babel-eslint/issues/730#issuecomment-447665682)